# Is it possible to reference a cell within a formula based off the value on another cell in Excel

Tags: excel, formula

I have been searching for an answer to this but maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing.
I would like to reference a cell based on the product of two cells.

For example

```
=A1:A(D2*E2)
```

so if D2=2 and E2=5 the formula would return =A1:A10

Is doing something like this possible?

Comment: Check out indirect(), lots of examples doing similar things on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
=A1:INDEX(A:A,D2*E2)
```

which is at least only semi-volatile, unlike `INDIRECT()`.

Comment: =INDIRECT("H15:H" & D2*E2) Is what I got to work. Thank you

Comment: IMO `=H15:INDEX(H:H,D2*E2)` would be better